# how is time for re-execute a google app script calculated?

Tags: google-apps-script

let us suppose that i have a script running every 10 minutes, and now i add a code line

```
Utilities.sleep(30000)
```

in between.

will it now keep running every 10 minutes, or every 15 minutes?

Regards,

Comment: Are you talking about a script that is executed from a timed trigger of 10 minutes?

Comment: seems trivial to try it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a timed trigger is set to fire every 10 minutes, that is what it will do. It does not depend on how long the function takes to execute. In principle, you could have a 5 minute timeout inside a function that's triggered to run every 1 minute. Except that will quickly run into problems:

1. Total trigger-based execution time limit: [90 minutes per day](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas)
2. "There are too many scripts running simultaneously for this Google user account" (how many is "too many" is not documented as far as I know).